# RestAssured Json response verification with GPath

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, gpath

I receive the following response on a bad request against my API. I am using RestAssured for my rest response assertions.

```
{
    "message": "An entity of type topic was passed in an invalid format",
    "meta": {
        "display": {
            "topic": [
                {
                    "name": [
                        "must not be blank"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "contentType": [
                        "must not be blank"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "content": [
                        "must not be blank"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "version": [
                        "must not be blank"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to verify value of all the properties of the response. I am struggling to verify this path: `meta.display.topic.contentType`. I cannot come up with the GPath for it.

Here is the assertion that I am making:

```
given().body("{}").when()
            .post(BASE_URL)
            .prettyPeek()
            .then()
            .statusCode(400)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body("message", is("An entity of type topic was passed in an invalid format"),
                    "meta.display.topic.contentType", is("must not be blank"));
```

Since the path is not correct, assertion always fails.

Comment: from your example response Gpath should be `meta.display.topic[1].contentType[0]`

Comment: I do not want to hardcode array positions inside of a topic object, is there a way to avoid doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid hardcoded array positions for **topic** object following will work:

```
meta.display.topic.find { it.contentType != null }.contentType[0]
```

Comment: It works, but I didn't want to sprinkle my code with Groovy scripts, even tiny ones, I would assume that there would be some path matcher or smth, that would facilitate things like such.